# Reshaping when variables are not unique

Tags: statistics, stata, reshape, stata-macros

I have a dataset below and I want to reshape it in Stata.

```
clear 
input int id str7 item float consumption 
1   "food123"   0.72
1   "food174"   0.51
1   "food167"   0.76
1   "food160"   0.02
1   "fruit240"  0.52
1   "fruit263"  0.06
1   "fruit254"  100.00
1   "drink345"  0.25
1   "drink340"  0.60
1   "vegtable466"   0.87
1   "vegtable440"   0.44
2   "food123"   0.26
2   "food167"   0.52
2   "food120"   0.44
2   "food160"   0.16
2   "fruit240"  0.09
2   "fruit242"  0.65
2   "fruit263"  0.80
2   "fruit230"  0.60
2   "fruit254"  0.32
2   "drink340"  0.90
2   "drink345"  0.05
2   "vegtable466"   0.24
2   "vegtable460"   0.78
end
```

The result is (the row is id and the columns are items):

[image: Result]

When I use `reshape`, it shows "values of variable `item` not unique within `id`".
My code is:

```
reshape wide consumption, i(id) j(item) string
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `reshape` command works fine for your data example, so long as you use an appropriate type for `item`.

```
input int id str11  item float consumption
```

Using `str7` just truncates the description and causes spurious duplicates.